# How to run rails driven app (Snorby) on different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails

Sorry for being such a newbie but is it possible to make rails driven app (Snorby) being started on port different than 3000?
How to do this? I've changed the ports from `3000` to `9000` at **snorby_config.yml** but it still running port 3000...

```
$ cd /usr/local/var/www/snorby && bundle exec rails server -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-07-30 17:37:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-30 17:37:28] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-darwin14.3.0]
[2015-07-30 17:37:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=40591 port=3000
cache: [GET /] miss
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`$ cd /usr/local/var/www/snorby && bundle exec rails server -p 9000 -e production`

Comment: -p stands for port

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please help me with another issue: http://superuser.com/questions/992695/deploying-ruby-app-with-apache-2-4